# How do I set the font & font-size of the numbering in a XWPFDocument (apache poi)?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Currently creating the numbering like this:

```
    CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
    cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

    CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
    cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.DECIMAL);
    cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("%1.");
    cTLvl.addNewStart().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

    XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
    XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

    BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
    BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

    XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
    tmpParagraph.setPageBreak(true);
    tmpParagraph.setNumID(numID);
```

This is working fine as paragraphs are getting correctly numbered, but I'm lost trying to find a way to change the size of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to solve this by combining googling & reverse engineering/diffing of the contents in a document I worked in.

Here is 'a' solution setting the numbering font size to 18:

```
private String getNumberingXMLString(int fontSize) {
    return  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
            + "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
            + "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/>"
            + "<w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:sz w:val=\"" + fontSize*2 +"\"/><w:szCs w:val=\""+fontSize*2 +"\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
            + "</w:abstractNum>";
}
...
...
...
            CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(getNumberingXMLString(18));
            CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);
            XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
            XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
            BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
            numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);
```

If I'm undertanding this correctly, this could also be solved using

```
     cTLvl.getRPr().addNewSz().setVal(...);
     cTLvl.getRPr().addNewSzCs().setVal(...);
```

In the code I provided in the question